# unable to install bower in windows 10 using npm

Tags: npm, bower

I am unable to install bower in windows 10 using npm.

The Error message I get is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g  bower
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 74.122.238.10:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a network connection timed out.

Check your Internet connectivity and try the command again later.

If you are using a proxy for your internet, npm needs to be configured properly for that. See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy.